# "Imaginary-time" argument in high energy physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, complex-numbers, time-evolution, wick-rotation

In many-body physics, there are many "imaginary-time" techniques, such as Matsubara  Green's function, imaginary-time path integral and others. It seems that these concepts are frequently used in condensed matter literature.

However, so far I have not found these concepts used at high energy physics. They only care about the "usual" Green's function, and regularize the divergent Feynman diagram by renormalization techniques. Is there any example adopting these techniques in high energy physics? Also, is there any reference (in both condensed matter and high energy) of introductory texts for imaginary-time path integral?